# How to avoid background color opactity issue when I animate an image or smth else?

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics, 2d

This screenshot and code snippet will show you my trouble. How to avoid this? May be I do this in wrong way? I would like to see some code example, if possible.

[image]

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
 let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

 canvas.width = 500;
 canvas.height = 500;

 let image = new Image();

 image.src= "https://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/identity/HTML5_Badge_256.png";

 function rand(min, max)
 {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
 }

 image.addEventListener("load", function()
 {

  let top = canvas.width / 2 - image.width / 2;
  let left = canvas.height / 2 - image.height / 2;

  function render()
  {

   top += rand(-2, 2);
   left += rand(-2, 2);


   ctx.save();
   ctx.globalAlpha = 0.05;
   ctx.fillStyle = "#9ea7b8";
   ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   ctx.restore();
   ctx.drawImage(image, top, left, image.width, image.height);
   requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  render();
 });
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem**

The best way I can think of to describe this artifact is to call it a rounding error. One thing that people tend to forget, is that when you draw to a canvas, you are actually writing to a bitmap. Effectively an image. The alpha value per pixel is an integer, x, where 0 <= x <= 255.

So, when you say:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.05;
ctx.fillStyle = "#9ea7b8";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.restore();
ctx.drawImage(image, top, left, image.width, image.height);
```

You are drawing a mostly transparent square which won't make anything disappear fully. For instance, if a pixel has a color of `rgba(254,255,255,255)` and you draw over it with a white square at 0.05 opacity, `rgba(255,255,255,12)`, it will pull the red from `254` up to `254.05`. This needs to be an integer, though, so it gets rounded down, and will never fully become the color it is approaching.

**Now how to fix it**

1. One way I can think to fix this is to basically make a snake. You can use a circular array to store the positions of each, progressively more transparent image, and then draw them once you clear the screen. There is a problem with this though, it takes up a bit more room, and takes a bit longer to draw.
2. You can go through the image data and if a pixel is close enough, you make it what you want. I won't provide finished code for you, but you can use [ctx.getImageData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData).

Pixel comparisons should be similar to

```
if(abs(actualRed-targetRed) < tolerance && abs(actualGreen-targetGreen) < tolerance....){
    actualRed=targetRed; 
    actualGreen=targetGreen...
}
```

3. [This page](http://rectangleworld.com/blog/archives/214) has a very interesting approach. Basically, it manipulates the alpha values of the picture directly, instead of drawing a transparent picture over it. You want a background color, apparently. This starts to complicate things, but not too badly. I would suggest separating the dynamic images from the static images. You can have two canvases that are stacked on top of one another (this is best practice, actually). Or you can just [set the background of the canvas](https://www.google.com/search?q=canvas+background+image&oq=canvas+background+image).

Hopefully this helped.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after a lot of tries, job is done. Every frame I draw full path.

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
 let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 let tail = 20;

 canvas.width = 800;
 canvas.height = 600;

 let image = new Image();

 let opacity = [];

 image.src= "https://www.html5rocks.com/static/images/identity/HTML5_Badge_256.png";

 for(let i = 1; i <= tail; i++)
 {
  opacity.push(i / tail);
 }


 function rand(min, max)
 {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
 }

 image.addEventListener("load", function()
 {

  let frames = [];

  frames.push({
   x: canvas.width / 2 - image.width / 2,
   y: canvas.height / 2 - image.height / 2
  });

  for (let i = 1; i < tail; i++)
  {
   frames.push({
    x: frames[i - 1].x + rand(-2, 2),
    y: frames[i - 1].y + rand(-2, 2)
   });
  }

  function render()
  {

   frames.shift();
   frames.push({
    x: frames[frames.length - 1].x + rand(-2, 2),
    y: frames[frames.length - 1].y + rand(-2, 2)
   });

   ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
   ctx.fillStyle = "#9ea7b8";
   ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

   for(let i = 0; i < tail; i++)
   {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.drawImage(image, frames[i].x, frames[i].y, image.width, image.height);
    ctx.globalAlpha = opacity[tail - 1 - i];
    ctx.fillRect(frames[i].x - tail, frames[i].y - tail, image.width + tail + tail, image.height + tail + tail);
    ctx.restore();
   }

   requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  render();
 });
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Very nice! I like how you approached it. I also completely forgot that `let` is a thing. Thank you for reminding me!